# transfer selected row to another table

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I fetched the data from the database and display it in a table with check boxes. What I
want to do is the selected row should move into the second table.There's something wrong with my js and i cant figure it out. It doesn't work. Here's the code

```
 $result=mysql_query($query)
or die('Error executing query'.mysql_error());

echo "<table id='tbl1' style='border: solid 1px red'>";
    echo "<tr><td>File Name";
    echo "<td>File Size";
    echo "<td>Date Modified</td></tr>";

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {

 echo"<tr><td><input type='checkbox'  class='chkclass' name=''  value='$row[fid]' />"; 
 echo "$row[file_path]";
 echo "<td>$row[file_size]";
 echo "<td>$row[file_modified]</td>"; 
}
 echo"</table>";

  echo "<table id='tbl2' style='border: solid 1px blue; margin-top: 10px'>";
  echo"</table>";
```

Here's the js code:

```
(function(){
        $("#tbl1 input:checkbox.chkclass").click(function(){
         if ($(this).is(":checked"))
           {
             $(this).closest("tr").clone().appendTo("#tbl2");
           }
        else
          {
            var index = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-index");
            var findRow = $("#tbl2 tr[data-index='" + index + "']");
            findRow.remove();
         }
       });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues with your code

**1)** You are not closing your `<td>` properly

**2)** You are not using `data-index` attribute  in `tbl1` `<tr>`

The `html` should be like this

```
<table id='tbl1' style='border: solid 1px red'>
    <tr>
       <td>File Name</td>
       <td>File Size</td>
       <td>Date Modified</td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-index="5">
       <td>
          <input type='checkbox'  class='chkclass' name=''  value='1' />       
       </td>
       <td>500,b</td>
       <td>yes</td>
    </tr>
 </table>

  <table id='tbl2' style='border: solid 1px blue; margin-top: 10px'>
  </table>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ahzqw/)